# GDB with C++ that calls C Code

Tags: c++, c, cmake, gdb

I have a program written in C++ and C with the soirce. When I run the program with GDB, I get line numbers and access to the source for the C++ code but not the C code (i.e. stack trace points me to the C++ function called, but not for C). Additionally, I know the C code has errors in it.

Is there any way I can get the C code to show up in GDB as well? It would very useful to see which lines in the C code are causing me issues, but as it stands I only get memory addresses when the program crashes from an issue.

Additionally, I am generating my makefile using CMake with the setting `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, "-g -fopenmp -Wall")`

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? And how is everything built? You need to enable debugging support in all compilations, to make sure symbols etc are included.

Comment: Compile it with debugging options.

Comment: The makefile is generated by CMake, with set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, "-g -fopenmp -Wall"). Is there a flag that I need to include to enable debuggin for C as well? I thought -g would take care of that

Comment: The code is called in the sense that in one of the C++ files, there is an `extern "C" int fastlap(...);` where `int fastlap(...)` is the function being called, and is written in C, in a separate file with its respective source files. This same C++ source file later calls `fastlap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating debug info for C++ code only, not the C code. You need to also set the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS, "-g")
```

Add more options as needed.

Comment: Precisely what I needed, thank you for your answer.